# Get a handle on the running Visual Studio instance (DTE) from powershell

Tags: visual-studio-2010, powershell, nuget

How do I get an instance of a currently running Visual Studio instance ?
I need to access Visual Studio object model (DTE) outside of the Visual Studio.

I want to run a nuget install script from powershell ise - to be able to better understand what the script is doing and why it's not doing what i expect

So I want to feed in all the parameters that install.ps1 takes in

```
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string]   $installPath,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string]   $toolsPath,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]            $package,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]            $project
)
```

It's easy to set the strings parameters, gowever

project and package are the tricky ones

I do have access to nuget cmdlets. I followed [this](http://community.sharpdevelop.net/blogs/mattward/archive/2011/06/12/InstallingNuGetPackagesOutsideVisualStudio.aspx) post to achieve that.

So I import-module PackageManagement.Cmdlets.dll

That all works fine

now when I attempt something like

```
$project = Get-Project -name SmartCom.Registration.Logic
```

I get this message "A project must be open to run this command." so I guess I first need to hook into vs via DTE and open a solution and then load a project in order for this to work?

I know that there are things like PowerConsole that hook up with vs automatically, but in this case I want it to work outside of the vs so i can debug it with powershell isa

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The post you linked to uses SharpDevelop to allow the use of NuGet PowerShell cmdlets outside of Visual Studio. It has no dependency on Visual Studio so I do not believe opening an instance of Visual Studio will help you.

The error is being displayed because there is no solution currently open. To open a solution you can use the **set-project** cmdlet:

```
    set-project MyProject d:\Projects\MyProject\MySolution.sln
```

Then you should be able to call the **get-project** cmdlet.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming Visual Studio is running (and there's only one instance) then you can do this:

```
PS> $dte = [runtime.interopservices.marshal]::GetActiveObject("visualstudio.dte")
PS> $dte

Name                   : Microsoft Visual Studio
...
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: How about multiple instances? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61106505/getting-dte-for-running-visual-studio-instances-from-powershell