# sharpdevelop nuget: set-project says unknown project

Tags: powershell, nuget, sharpdevelop

I am trying to follow this [post](http://community.sharpdevelop.net/blogs/mattward/archive/2011/06/12/InstallingNuGetPackagesOutsideVisualStudio.aspx) 
to add nuget packages to my solution through the command line.

However, when I try to run the following command:

```
Install-package nuget -solution mysolution.sln -projectName myproject
```

I get  the following error,

```
Can't read Microsoft Solution file format 12.00
Install-Package : A project must be open to run this command.
At line:1 char:16
+ install-package <<<<   nuget -solution mysolution.sln -projectname
 myproject
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Install-Package], Invalid OperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoProjectOpen,ICSharpCode.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.InstallPackageCmdlet
```

Based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8584896/get-a-handle-on-the-running-visual-studio-instance-dte-from-powershell), I tried setting the project name

```
set-project myproject mysolution.sln
```

I get this error,

```
Can't read Microsoft Solution file format 12.00
    Set-Project : Unknown project: myproject
    At line:1 char:12
    + set-project <<<<  myproject mysolution.sln
        + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Set-Project], ApplicationException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ApplicationException,ICSharpCode.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.SetProjectCmdlet
```

I checked the sln file and it has the exact project name that I am trying to add. Any guesses on what could be the problem? Alternatively, is there any way to find the project names of my solution through some command so that I can cross-check?

Comment: What version of SharpDevelop are you using? There was a [bug fix](https://github.com/mrward/SharpDevelop/commit/1c8095f0c1ac316bf404272da9788c872538ced3) applied for problems resolving the solution. It looks like the solution is not being found so the project is not available.

Comment: Version: 4.4.2, Build: 9749

Comment: Based on your suggestion, I tried giving the full path to the sln file. I am still getting the same error though.

Comment: Yeah, not sure why it is not working. I will have to debug the code to see what is happening.

Comment: I just realized that the error starts with this line:
"Can't read Microsoft Solution file format 12.00"
The reason I didn't notice it earlier was that it is in White, whereas the rest of the error is shown in Red.
I am using VS 2013.

Comment: Ah OK that would be the problem then. SharpDevelop 4 does not support the more recent solution file format.